# Nodejs: What's the proper way to pipe to a buffer / string

Tags: node.js, stream

In node I can pipe to a file like this:

```
let outStream = fs.createWriteStream('./unzipped.html')
req.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(outStream)
```

and read it back later with:

```
let data = fs.readFileSync('./unzipped.html')
```

But I don't want to create a file. What kind of stream am I looking for?

Comment: Also, there are a lot of NPM packages providing utility pipes for this sort of thing.  https://github.com/jasonpincin/stream-to-string

Comment: @Brad, Thanks but the other question / answers don't show how to create the stream (other than the fs stream which I'm trying to avoid.) I also want to avoid a new dependency. I'll stick with the temp file if there's no clean way to do this.

Comment: You *have* a stream, you're piping it to a file now.  And, the accepted answer on that question shows how you can write this code manually.  Just concatenate chunks to a buffer until the `end` event.

Comment: You're talking about stream.Readable ? My question is about how to implement that which the answer doesn't cover.

Comment: Am I not understanding what you're asking?  Your question asks how to pipe data to a buffer/string.  To do that, you simply consume the `data` and `end` events.  On `data`, add it to your buffer/string.  On `end`, you're done.  If for some reason you want to add another pipe (which doesn't sound necessary), you could use the built-in Through pipe.

Comment: I'm asking what kind of stream to use. I ended up going with stream.PassThrough